# Tessellating/Subdividing a quad

Tags: c#, xna, mathematics, recursion

I am creating a quad that starts as a single quad, then divides itself multiple times (from 1 to 4 to 16 to 64 to 256 and so forth) but I have encountered an issue. When I get to 64 sub divisions only 16 quads are shown.

[image]

Here is my `Quad` class:

```
class Quad {
        GraphicsDevice device;

        private int rows = 1;
        private int columns = 1;

        private int width = 64;
        private int height = 64;

        private Quad[,] quads;
        private Quad parent;

        private List<VertexPositionColor> vertices;
        private List<int> indices;

        private Vector2 index;

        public List<VertexPositionColor> Vertices {
            get { return vertices; }
            set { }
        }

        public List<int> Indices {
            get { return indices; }
            set { }
        }

        public Vector2 Index {
            get { return index; }
            set { index = value; }
        }

        public int Width {
            get { return width; }
            set { }

        }

        public int Height {
            get { return height; }
            set { }
        }

        public void SetSize(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        public void SetParent(Quad parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        public List<Quad> GetChildren() {
            List<Quad> quadList = new List<Quad>();

            if (quads != null) {
                for (int x = 0; x < this.quads.GetLength(0); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < this.quads.GetLength(1); y++) {
                        quadList.AddRange(quads[x, y].GetChildren());

                        OutputBuffer.STRING_BUFFER.Clear();
                    }
                }

                OutputBuffer.Add("Children Count: " + quadList.Count);

                return quadList;
            }

            quadList.Add(this);
            return quadList;
        }

        public Quad(ref GraphicsDevice device) {
            this.device = device;
        }

        public void Construct() {
            ConstructVertices();
            ConstructIndices();
        }

        private void ConstructVertices() {
            vertices = new List<VertexPositionColor>();

            Vector3 parentPosition = parent != null ? new Vector3(parent.Index.X * parent.Width, 0, parent.Index.Y * parent.Height) : Vector3.Zero;

            Vector3 backLeft = new Vector3(index.X * width, 0, index.Y * height + height) + parentPosition;
            Vector3 backRight = new Vector3(index.X * width + width, 0, index.Y * height + height) + parentPosition;
            Vector3 frontLeft = new Vector3(index.X * width, 0, index.Y * height) + parentPosition;
            Vector3 frontRight = new Vector3(index.X * width + width, 0, index.Y * height) + parentPosition;

            vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(frontLeft, Color.White));
            vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(frontRight, Color.White));
            vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(backLeft, Color.White));
            vertices.Add(new VertexPositionColor(backRight, Color.White));
        }

        private void ConstructIndices() {
            indices = new List<int>();

            indices.AddRange(new int[] { 0, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0 }.ToList());
        }

        public void ConstructChildren() {
            if (quads == null) {
                quads = new Quad[2, 2];

                for (int x = 0; x < quads.GetLength(0); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < quads.GetLength(1); y++) {
                        quads[x, y] = new Quad(ref device);
                        quads[x, y].Index = new Vector2(x, y);
                        quads[x, y].SetSize(width / 2, height / 2);
                        quads[x, y].SetParent(this);
                        quads[x, y].Construct();
                    }
                }

                this.vertices = null;
                this.indices = null;
            } else {
                for (int x = 0; x < quads.GetLength(0); x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < quads.GetLength(1); y++) {
                        quads[x, y].ConstructChildren();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I think the problem is when the vertices are being constructed. I think those four sets of 16 quads are being drawn on top of each other. And I definitely think it's doing the subdivision.

Here's the `QuadRenderer` class (note that I just hacked to together to test the above, so don't expect quality code):

```
class QuadRenderer {
    GraphicsDevice device;

    Quad quad;

    Matrix view;
    Matrix projection;
    Matrix world;

    Effect effect;

    Vector2 position = new Vector2(16, 16);

    int columns = 2;
    int rows = 2;

    KeyboardState previousKbState;

    public QuadRenderer(GraphicsDevice device) {
        this.device = device;

        this.quad = new Quad(ref device);
        this.quad.Construct();
    }

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager content) {
        this.effect = content.Load<Effect>("Effects\\Effects");
    }

    public void Update() {
        ProcessInput();

        view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(position.X, 80, position.Y), new Vector3(position.X, 0, 16 + position.Y), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 1.0f, 300.0f);
    }

    public void ProcessInput() {
        KeyboardState kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) {
            position.Y += 2;
        }
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) {
            position.Y -= 2;
        }
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) {
            position.X += 2;
        }
        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) {
            position.X -= 2;
        }

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) &&
            !previousKbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) {
                this.quad.ConstructChildren();
        }

        this.previousKbState = kbState;
    }

    public void Draw() {
        device.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.DepthBuffer, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

        RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
        rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
        rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
        device.RasterizerState = rs;

        Matrix world = Matrix.Identity * Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(64 / 2, 0, 64 / 2));
        effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["Coloured"];
        effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(view);
        effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
        effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(world);

        foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes) {
            pass.Apply();

            foreach (Quad quad in this.quad.GetChildren()) {
                //world *= Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(quad.Index.X * quad.Width, 0, quad.Index.Y * quad.Height));

                device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, quad.Vertices.ToArray(), 0, quad.Vertices.Count, quad.Indices.ToArray(), 0, quad.Indices.Count / 3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what do *you* think is causing it? Awfully close to here's my code find my problem.

Comment: are you sure that it is even doing the subdivision to 64, or could it just be stagnating at 16?

Comment: I think the problem is when the vertices are being constructed. I think those four sets of 16 quads are being drawn on top of each other. And I defiantly think it's doing the subdivision.

Comment: @gardian06 Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I was not taking the parent index and adding it to the child's index, I  changed the following line:

```
quads[x, y].Index = new Vector2(x + index.X * 2, y + index.Y * 2);
```

and removed the following (and all references to it):

```
Vector3 parentPosition = parent != null ? new Vector3(parent.Index.X * parent.Width, 0, parent.Index.Y * parent.Height) : Vector3.Zero;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not showing all the code but I suggest making `width` and `height` floating point values. You are dividing them by 2 at each subdivision, meaning they'll eventually reach zero.

Comment: OK, I just added more of the code into the original post. And thanks for the tip, silly of me to make them integers :D

Comment: OK, I changed the types to floating point values, but it still has not fixed my problem :(